# Step definitions for cucumber data tables for storing correct answers

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to find a way to test multiple choice questions. The structure is that a lesson has 8 stages and each stage contains multiple choice questions with only one correct answer. The loading of the questions is random each time so i have been looking for the best way to test whether the correct answer is clicked. For this reason i have created a data table with two columns which is obviously more extensive than this but is along these lines:

```
| what is the opposite of true | false        |
| what comes after tuesday     |  wednesday   |
```

In the feature test i have written that it is testing a correct answer match. Later I was then hoping to find a way to test that if the question and answer match were not in the data table then it is incorrect. Would someone be able to explain how I would go about doing the test definitions for this?

I have tried to use the rows_hash method but I am getting the following error

```
 undefined method `rows_hash' for -3634850196505698949:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Given(/^a list of answer\-value pairs$/) do |table|
    @question_answer_table = hash
end

When(/^I choose a match$/) do
  hash = @question_answer_table
  @question_answer_table.rows_hash
  return false if hash[question].nil?
  return hash[question] == answer
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [rows_hash](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/1.2.1/Cucumber/Ast/Table:rows_hash) method will help you.

```
def question_correct?(cucumber_table, question, answer)
  hash = cucumber_table.rows_hash
  return false if hash[question].nil?
  return hash[question] == answer
end
```

The code works by converting a two column data table into a hash, where the first column is the key and the second is the value.

Keep in mind that this method requires your data table to be limited to two columns.

Comment: This is amazing thank you!! looking at the argument there should i have a question and answer heading within the table? Also where does cucumber_table come in to it?

Comment: The cucumber_table parameter is your data table. So, define a step like:
`Given a list of answer-value pairs` followed by your data table. Set an instance variable (like @question_answer_table), and then in your other steps you can call that method with your instance variable as the first parameter. You do not need to put a question and answer heading in the table.

Comment: For some reason I am getting undefined method rows hash could you offer any suggestions? I have edited the above question to include the code

Comment: In your first step, you defined the hash to have the variable name 'table'. So, the code should read `@question_answer_table = table`. In your second step, you need to set hash equal to not just the table, but the row_hash, so `hash = @question_answer_table.rows_hash`

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this much easier, if you don't try and do this in Cucumber using data tables. Instead push all that detail down to helper methods that are called by the step definitions. To start doing this you need to write a more abstract feature.

The first thing you need to do is to get the simplest possible lesson to work with. So

```
Given a simple lesson
When I answer the questions correctly
Then I should see I passed the lesson
```

This is the scenario you'll use to 'drive' your development.

You can implement these steps really easily by delegating e.g.

```
Given "a simple lesson" do
  @lesson = create_simple_lesson
end

When "I answer the questions correctly" do
  answer_questions lesson: @lesson
end

Then "I should see I passed the lesson" do
  expect(page).to have_content "You passed"
end
```

To get this to work you'll have to implement some helper methods

```
module QuestionaireStepHelper
  def create_simple_lesson
    ...

  def answer_questions lesson: nil
    ...


end
World QuestionaireStepHelper
```

What this does is move your technical problem into a new domain. Here you have the full power of a programming language to do whatever you want: so you can do things like

- create Questions that have answers and know what the correct answer is
- ask Questions for thier correct answer, so you can answer them correctly
- add questions to a lesson
  ...

Remember because you are still in the Cucumber::World, you have the full power to

- drive your browser
- access your database
  ...

When you have finished this you'll have lots of tools to write scenarios like

```
Given a simple lesson
When I answer the questions incorrectly
Then I should see I failed the lesson
```

and so on.